# Can 2 smartphones comunicate with each other over bluetooth if bluetooth is turned off?

Tags: applications, samsung, bluetooth, geolocation

Such a situation:2 smartphones have the same app and they are in the same bluetooth range. Can the app detect proximity between 2 devices over bluetooth if bluetooth is turned off on 2 devices

Comment: If Bluetooth is off on both devices how should they communicate?

Comment: @Robert I don't  know. I read somewhere that for example  NFC can communicate  in such a way.

Comment: It won't communicate with Bluetooth.

Comment: @Jacewerlock using NFC two devices can exchange some data but they have to be very close to each other. The maximum distance is usually about 15 cm and the amount of data that can be transmitted is very small (a few hundred bytes?). And for NFC it is the same as with Bluetooth if NFC is disabled one one device communication will fail.

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear, what do you mean by "this way"?

Comment: @Robert  I mean for detecting proximity between 2 smartphones over wi fi direct   we also need to have 2 devices  that turned  on wi fi direct?                                                                                                           And is that mean that apps can't detect proximity between 2 smartphones if users haven't enabled Bluetooth, Nfc, wi fi  direct ?